# Kill a suspended process?

Tags: kill, signals, background-process, process-management

I was slightly confused by:

```
% vim tmp
zsh: suspended   vim tmp
% kill %1
% jobs
[1]  + suspended   vim tmp
% kill -SIGINT %1
% jobs
[1]  + suspended   vim tmp
% kill -INT %1
% jobs
[1]  + suspended   vim tmp
```

So I resigned to just "do it myself" and wonder why later:

```
% fg
[1]  - continued   vim tmp
Vim: Caught deadly signal TERM
Vim: Finished.
zsh: terminated   vim tmp
%
```

Oh!

Makes sense really, now that I think about it, that `vim` has to be running in order for it's signal handler to be told to quit, and to do so.

But obviously not what I intended.

Is there a way to "wake and quit" in a single command? i.e., a built-in alias for `kill %N && fg %N`?

Why does resuming in the background not work? If I `bg` instead of `fg`, Vim stays alive until I `fg`, which sort of breaks my above intuition.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`vi-vi-vi` is of the devil. You must kill it with fire. Or `SIGKILL`:

```
kill -KILL %1
```

The builtin `kill`s are kind enough to send `SIGCONT` to suspended processes so that you don't have to do it yourself, but that won't help if the process  blocks the signal you're sending or if handling the signal causes the processes to become suspended again (if a background process tries to read from the terminal, by default, it'll be sent `SIGTTIN`, which suspends the process if unhandled).

Comment: Why on earth would you use SIGABRT? It's meant to indicate a program bug. SIGKILL is right here since you want to kill the program now whether it wants it or not.

Comment: Actually, it looks like `SIGTERM` wakes sleeping processes now, at least if they don't have handlers for it.  I think it didn't used to work this way, since I remember having to `bg` or `fg` something before it would receive the signal and go away.  But I tested with `awk 'BEGIN{while(42){}}' &`, and `strace kill $!`, and there's only one `kill(2)` system call, with `SIGTERM`.

Comment: If it doesn't work once, keep trying. On my hung-up Vim process, 1st time run of `kill -KILL %1` printed that the process was still suspended, while the 2nd run printed that it was killed (and 3rd time returned the error message "no such job" as expected if you were wondering).

Answer (score 6):

`vim` is installing signal handlers (and probably also setting `sigprocmask(2)`) to ignore common signals so that any files being edited are not lost due to a stray control+c or random kill signal. A simpler program is readily killed:

```
% cat busyloop.c
int main(void) {
for (;;) { ; }
return 0;
}
% make busyloop
cc     busyloop.c  -o busyloop
% ./busyloop
^Z
zsh: suspended  ./busyloop
% kill %1
%
[1]  + terminated  ./busyloop
```

Making `vim` exit (safely) would require a signal handler in `vim` that accepts `TERM` or `USR1` or something, saves (or discards?) any buffers, etc. What are you trying to do to need to make `vim` exit like this?

Comment: "What are you trying to do to need to make vim exit like this?" -- nothing, it was a genuinely "tmp" file that I was editing. `vim` was just an ill-conceived choice of program to test out suspension.

Comment: "ignore common signals so that any files being edited are not lost due to a stray control+c or random kill signal" -- but as soon as I `fg`'d ti did quit, it only stopped for as long as it was suspended?

Comment: @OllieFord: Only `SIGKILL` wakes a sleeping process so it can die.  Sending signals to a suspended process that has custom handlers for them does *not* wake it.  (Other than `SIGCONT`, the continue signal, of course.  `bg` and `fg` send `SIGCONT`.)